# Как запустить Blazor server приложение под vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor

Уважаемые Гуру!
Есть Blazor server приложение которое разрабатывалось по vs 2022.

1. Хочу перейти на vscode. Есть ли какие либо руководства по этому поводу?
2. Каким образом создаётся Blazor server приложение с нуля.
   Пример создания asp.net core в vscode я попробовал.